# Lbal and legend with spiderweb in dojox chart

Tags: charts, dojo

Here is my code :

I need to make a spiderweb graph with a legend in blue here.
3 axys

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
    <script>
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.axis2d.Default");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Default");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Spider");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.axis2d.Base");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Legend");

         dojo.ready(

                 function(Chart, Default, Default, Spider, Base,Legend){
             var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart("chart1");
             chart1.addPlot("default", {
             type:         "Spider",
             labelOffset:      -10,
             seriesFillAlpha:     0.2,
             markerSize:       3,
             precision:         0,
             divisions:         11,
             spiderType:          "polygon"
         });

        var data= [ {"J":0,"S":0,"I":0},
        {"J":10,"S":10,"I":10},
        {"J":7,"S":4,"I":8} ];

        chart1.addSeries("min", {data: data[0] }, { fill: "blue" });
        chart1.addSeries("max", {data: data[1] }, { fill: "blue" });
        chart1.addSeries("Test", {data: data[2] }, { fill: "blue",text: "Test" });
        chart1.render();
        chart1.removeSeries("min");
        chart1.removeSeries("max");
        var legendTwo = new Legend({chart: chart1}, "legendTwo");

        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart1" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"> </div>
    <div id="legendTwo"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

And i don't understand why the label and the legend doesn't print.

The remove is due to  a bug of dojox.

Regards

Bussiere

Comment: Haven't read it in-detail, but I suggest you take this up to dojo mailing lists. I had a similar problem of axes labels not listening to orientation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your issue, but since you are using the old module loading style (dojo.require), you need the full name of the Legend class:

```
var legendTwo = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({chart: chart1}, "legendTwo");
```